# EKS Redis - best practice how to configure PVC

Tags: kubernetes, redis, amazon-eks

I am planning to start to use Redis (helm bitnami) (master + slave) in my K8s.

What is the best way to configure PVC? Let is configure by helm config? Or prepare it manually?

As for me - I would like to prepare it manually (create AWS EBS + PV + PVC) - but how about multi az? Should I link my master/slave pods to exact nodes (affinity/nodeselector)? Without that - if Redis pod will start in different zone then PVC - it cant work?

What are the best practice to configure Redis + PVC in K8s?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is, you have a Kubernetes `StorageClass` which is baked by a CSI Driver that supports EBS [Link to AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/ebs-csi.html)

You can then make use of the `x.storageClass` flag in the [Helm-Chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/redis/#installing-the-chart) to reference your EBS `StorageClass`, then Kubernetes will request an EBS Volume from via the CSI Driver and configure all PV/PVC. So, you don't have to clean up something afterward in your AWS-Account directly. Keep attention to the `reclaimpolicy` in the `storageClass` [(Retain vs Delete)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#reclaim-policy).

Instead of assigning them to nodes directly, you could use the EKS node label `failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone` which could be used in a `podAntiAffinity`.

**Further Links:**

[Deploy a sample application and verify that the CSI driver is working](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/ebs-sample-app.html)

[Example of AntiAffinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#an-example-of-a-pod-that-uses-pod-affinity)

Comment: Yes, I already using CSI driver, and looks like I am using the schema you described now. But today, on my test cluster, I saw the issue I described. During Helm install - redis with sentiel option enabled, it was created 3 PVC by own. Today I changed count of nodes in my nodegroup and added a new one. 2 of 3 redis pods was scheduled to be created on new nodes and they can`t. The error was - they was scheduled to be created on one AZ zone node, but PVC/volumes was stayed in another. So, I had to delete old PVC for 2 nodes, and after that they was created new 2 PVC and started up.This is an issu

Comment: Looks like I need to use StorageClass =) Going to read about this, thank you!